# Problem to get rows from db with Diesel in Axum

Tags: sqlite, rust, rust-diesel, rust-axum

#### Context

I'm currently creating an API in Rust using `Axum` and `deadpool_diesel` for the database queries.

I'm encountering an error that I don't really understand and would need some help to fix it.

I'm currently discovering `Diesel` so I'm not a master at all of that crate.

#### Errors

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `(diesel::sql_types::Binary, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Bool, diesel::sql_types::Bool, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Binary>, diesel::sql_types::Timestamp, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Timestamp>, diesel::sql_types::Timestamp): load_dsl::private::CompatibleType<UserInformation, _>` is not satisfied
    --> src/controller/user.rs:11:51
     |
11   |     let all_users = users.load::<UserInformation>(&mut &conn).unwrap();
     |                           ----                    ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `load_dsl::private::CompatibleType<UserInformation, _>` is not implemented for `(diesel::sql_types::Binary, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Bool, diesel::sql_types::Bool, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Binary>, diesel::sql_types::Timestamp, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Timestamp>, diesel::sql_types::Timestamp)`
     |                           |
     |                           required by a bound introduced by this call
     |
     = help: the following other types implement trait `load_dsl::private::CompatibleType<U, DB>`:
               (ST0, ST1)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2, ST3)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6, ST7)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6, ST7, ST8)
             and 24 others
     = note: required for `table` to implement `LoadQuery<'_, _, UserInformation>`
note: required by a bound in `diesel::RunQueryDsl::load`
    --> /Users/midknight/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/diesel-2.1.0/src/query_dsl/mod.rs:1543:15
     |
1541 |     fn load<'query, U>(self, conn: &mut Conn) -> QueryResult<Vec<U>>
     |        ---- required by a bound in this associated function
1542 |     where
1543 |         Self: LoadQuery<'query, Conn, U>,
     |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `RunQueryDsl::load`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `UserInformation: FromSqlRow<_, _>` is not satisfied
    --> src/controller/user.rs:11:51
     |
11   |     let all_users = users.load::<UserInformation>(&mut &conn).unwrap();
     |                           ----                    ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `FromSqlRow<_, _>` is not implemented for `UserInformation`
     |                           |
     |                           required by a bound introduced by this call
     |
     = help: the following other types implement trait `FromSqlRow<ST, DB>`:
               <(T1, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, Untyped), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, Untyped), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, Untyped), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, Untyped), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, Untyped), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6, Untyped), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6, ST7, Untyped), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6, ST7, ST8, Untyped), __DB>>
             and 23 others
     = note: required for `table` to implement `LoadQuery<'_, _, UserInformation>`
note: required by a bound in `diesel::RunQueryDsl::load`
    --> /Users/midknight/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/diesel-2.1.0/src/query_dsl/mod.rs:1543:15
     |
1541 |     fn load<'query, U>(self, conn: &mut Conn) -> QueryResult<Vec<U>>
     |        ---- required by a bound in this associated function
1542 |     where
1543 |         Self: LoadQuery<'query, Conn, U>,
     |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `RunQueryDsl::load`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `&deadpool::managed::Object<Manager<SqliteConnection>>: LoadConnection` is not satisfied
    --> src/controller/user.rs:11:51
     |
11   |     let all_users = users.load::<UserInformation>(&mut &conn).unwrap();
     |                           ----                    ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `LoadConnection` is not implemented for `&deadpool::managed::Object<Manager<SqliteConnection>>`
     |                           |
     |                           required by a bound introduced by this call
     |
     = help: the trait `LoadConnection` is implemented for `SqliteConnection`
     = note: required for `table` to implement `LoadQuery<'_, &deadpool::managed::Object<Manager<SqliteConnection>>, UserInformation>`
note: required by a bound in `diesel::RunQueryDsl::load`
    --> /Users/midknight/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/diesel-2.1.0/src/query_dsl/mod.rs:1543:15
     |
1541 |     fn load<'query, U>(self, conn: &mut Conn) -> QueryResult<Vec<U>>
     |        ---- required by a bound in this associated function
1542 |     where
1543 |         Self: LoadQuery<'query, Conn, U>,
     |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `RunQueryDsl::load`
```

#### Code

```rust
use axum::extract::State;
use deadpool_diesel::sqlite::Pool;
use diesel::RunQueryDsl;

use crate::{schema::users::dsl::*, models::user::UserInformation};


pub async fn get_all_users(State(pool): State<Pool>) {
    let conn = pool.get().await.unwrap();

    let all_users = users.load::<UserInformation>(&mut &conn).unwrap();
}
```

```rust
// schema.rs

diesel::table! {
    users {
        id -> Binary,
        username -> Text,
        name -> Text,
        surname -> Text,
        email -> Text,
        password_hash -> Text,
        disabled -> Bool,
        superuser -> Bool,
        profile_picture -> Nullable<Binary>,
        creation_date -> Timestamp,
        last_login -> Nullable<Timestamp>,
        last_update -> Timestamp,
    }
}
```

```rust
// model.rs

use chrono::NaiveDateTime;
use diesel::{Insertable, Selectable, Queryable};

use crate::schema::users;

#[derive(Selectable)]
#[diesel(table_name = users)]
#[diesel(check_for_backend(diesel::sqlite::Sqlite))]
pub struct UserInformation {
    #[diesel(sql_type = Binary)]
    pub id: Vec<u8>,
    #[diesel(sql_type = Text)]
    pub username: String,
    #[diesel(sql_type = Text)]
    pub name: String,
    #[diesel(sql_type = Text)]
    pub surname: String,
    #[diesel(sql_type = Text)]
    pub email: String,
    #[diesel(sql_type = Bool)]
    pub disabled: bool,
    #[diesel(sql_type = Bool)]
    pub superuser: bool,
    #[diesel(sql_type = Nullable<Binary>)]
    pub profile_picture: Option<Vec<u8>>,
    #[diesel(sql_type = Timestamp)]
    pub creation_date: NaiveDateTime,
    #[diesel(sql_type = Nullable<Timestamp>)]
    pub last_login: Option<NaiveDateTime>,
    #[diesel(sql_type = Timestamp)]
    pub last_update: NaiveDateTime,
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your struct is missing the required [`FromSqlRow`](https://docs.rs/diesel/latest/diesel/deserialize/trait.FromSqlRow.html) implementation which can be implemented by deriving [`Queryable`](https://docs.rs/diesel/latest/diesel/deserialize/derive.Queryable.html):

```
#[derive(Selectable, Queryable)] // <----------
#[diesel(table_name = users)]
#[diesel(check_for_backend(diesel::sqlite::Sqlite))]
pub struct UserInformation {
   // ...
}
```

You are also missing the `password_hash` field that your table has. Either add it to the model definition, or if you have omitted it on purpose you can add a `SELECT` clause to only get those fields (since you've already derived `Selectable`):

```
let all_users = users
    .select(UserInformation::as_select()) // <----------
    .load::<UserInformation>(&mut conn)
    .unwrap();
```

Comment: I don't want to retrieve the password_hash for security reasons, so I should do a new struct that contains every rows of the table users and and put it as <T> in the load method right?

Comment: The method shown at the bottom of my answer using `::as_select()` is for your struct without the field and will not retrieve the password hash.